# Is this bridge pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, bridge

Let's assume a system is responsible for managing subscription payment from accounts. For example, if user has bussiness account we want every six amount charge his account for some fee. Let's say that we want implement it as task and we want to use different implementations for that task (Quartz, Java task,...). A Image below illustrates that.
[image: UML claass diagram]

It would not have different abstractions(SubscribePayment here).

Is this a bridge pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Is seems that this is the bridge pattern. I found some links.

1. https://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/C++/pattern-examples4.pdf

Here the pattern has only one abstraction implementation, Tree, and many implementator.

2. https://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/teaching/2501ICT/pdf/SDPatt.pdf

Here the pattern also has only one abstraction implementation, Seat, and many Seat implementator (AIMSeat, SARTSeat)